# keycloak UserCredentialValueModel class is not found

Tags: java, keycloak

keycloak `UserCredentialValueModel` class is not found. I added keycloak 8.0.0 to a pom.xml, but I cannot find it when trying to import it.
found an example here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi

```
​@Override
​public void processAction(RequiredActionContext context) {
   ​String answer = (context.getHttpRequest().getDecodedFormParameters().getFirst("answer"));
   ​UserCredentialValueModel model = new UserCredentialValueModel();
   ​model.setValue(answer);
   ​model.setType(SecretQuestionAuthenticator.CREDENTIAL_TYPE);
   ​context.getUser().updateCredentialDirectly(model);
   ​context.success();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using UserCredentialModel model = new UserCredentialModel(credentialId, type, challengeResponse). That solved my problem.